# Validating a Date

Tags: javascript, forms, function

I have an assignment for javascript class that requires me to validate a date. The teacher provided a function for the actual validation, but the rest is up to me.  I've been working on this for a couple hours and I'm stuck. Here's what I have so far...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Date Validation</title>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var month = document.validateDate.month.value;
var day = document.validateDate.day.value;
var year = document.validateDate.year.value;



function validDate( month, day, year) 
{ 
   // Test for leap year 
    if ((year % 400 == 0) || (year % 4 == 0) &&                 
       !(year % 100 == 0)) 
          leap = true; 
    else 
          leap = false; 

    // Validate date                              // Assume a valid date-test otherwise
    if (year < 1900 || year > 2050)               // year must be four digits and      
        return false;                             //     within reasonable range 
    else if ((month < 1) || (month > 12) ||       // test general date and month range 
             (day < 1) || (day > 31)) 
        return false;      
    else if (((month == 4) || (month == 6) ||     // test 30 Day months 
              (month == 9) || (month == 11)) && (day == 31)) 
        return false;      
    else if (month == 2 && leap && day > 29)      // test February leap years 
        return false;          
    else if (month == 2 &&  !leap && day > 28)    // test February NON-leap years 
        return false;          
    else 
        return true;                              // otherwise, date is OK 

} 
</script>
<body>

<h1>Date Validator</h1>

<p>Please enter a date to be validated, then press "Validate"</p>
<form action="" name="validateDate">
<select name="month">
<option value="1">January
<option value="2">February
<option value="3">March
<option value="4">April
<option value="5">May
<option value="6">June
<option value="7">July
<option value="8">August
<option value="9">September
<option value="10">October
<option value="11">November
<option value="12">December
</select>

<select name="day">
<option value="1">1
<option value="2">2
<option value="3">3
<option value="4">4
<option value="5">5
<option value="6">6
<option value="7">7
<option value="8">8
<option value="9">9
<option value="10">10
<option value="11">11
<option value="12">12
<option value="13">13
<option value="14">14
<option value="15">15
<option value="16">16
<option value="17">17
<option value="18">18
<option value="19">19
<option value="20">20
<option value="21">21
<option value="22">22
<option value="23">23
<option value="24">24
<option value="25">25
<option value="26">26
<option value="27">27
<option value="28">28
<option value="29">29
<option value="30">30
<option value="31">31
</select>

<select name="year">
<option value="2011">2011
<option value="2012">2012
<option value="2013">2013
<option value="2014">2014
<option value="2015">2015
<option value="2016">2016
<option value="2017">2017
<option value="2018">2018
<option value="2019">2019
<option value="2020">2020
</select>

<input type="button" value="Validate" onclick="validDAte( month, day, year)"/>
<br />

<input type="text" name="textbox" style="width:275"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The actual function was what was provided. The variables "month", "day", and "year" I put there. I can get the values, but I can't get them to work in the function.

The net result is for the text box  at the bottom to say something like "1/1/2011 is a valid date." or "2/31/2011" is not a valid date." Please help...

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
<input type="button" value="Validate" onclick="validDAte( month, day, year)"/>
                                                     ^ misspelled
```

Which is misspelled (the a is capitalized wrongly in validDate). Maybe this is part of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function `validDate` at some point. Simply creating variables with the same name as the function parameters is not how it is done.

Presumably, you will have a button on the page, and when clicked, it will call the function and set the textbox's value.

The fiddle in another answer would work, but does a lot more than you were asked to do. The problem you are having stems from not properly understanding how to call a function. There are 2 sides to a function: a declaration and an invocation. The instructor gave you the declaration and asked you to create an invocation.

When you invoke a function, you replace the parameters in the declaration with the actual values to use. For example if you had a simple function:

```
function Add2(aValue) { return aValue + 2; }
```

your invocation would not necessarily mention the parameter named `aValue`. Rather, you would use the function name and replace the parameter with an actual value: `Add2(7)` would return 9.

Returning to your problem, you need to invoke the function `validDate` in your button handler. First, correct the spelling: javascript is case-sensitive. Then, replace each parameter name with the value from your form. I will show you one:

```
<input type="button" 
       value="Validate" 
       onclick="validDate(document.getElementById('month').value, day, year)"/>
```

I prefer `document.getElementById`. I leave filling in the other parameters (day, year) as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I know... I have the button, but it doesn't work properly... How?

Comment: I have added to my answer to point you in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/MqCeV/